# cmd batch file removing characters fails

Tags: powershell, azure, batch-file

I am trying to write a custom deploy.cmd for our azure web app deployment.  I created a test.cmd script to test removing the first and last character of a file path:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\npm.cmd"
```

The reason is because the powershell script gets upset if it is not quoted, but the cmd file needs it to not be quoted to run correctly.  My test script is:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=D:\home\site\wwwroot

SET NPM_CMD="D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\npm.cmd"
echo %NPM_CMD%
set NPM_CMD=%NPM_CMD:~1, -1%
echo %NPM_CMD%

pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
call "%NPM_CMD%" cache clean
call "%NPM_CMD%" install
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
```

This works and npm is called correctly.  So I took the:

```
set NPM_CMD=%NPM_CMD:~1, -1%
```

line and put it into my main deploy.cmd file:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Setup
:: -----        

echo starting deploy.cmd
echo -------------------
echo %*
SET all=%*
SET NPM_GLOBAL=%1
SET NPM_INFO=%2

echo all: %all%
echo NPM_GLOBAL: %NPM_GLOBAL%
echo NPM_INFO: %NPM_INFO%

SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=D:\home\site\wwwroot

if NPM_GLOBAL=="True" (
    REM install specific version of NPM
    echo installing specific version of NPM @ %NPM_INFO%
    npm install -g npm@%NPM_INFO%
    %NPM_CMD%=npm
) else (    
    SET NPM_CMD=%NPM_INFO%
    set NPM_CMD=%NPM_CMD:~1, -1%
    echo %NPM_CMD%
    echo NPM_CMD set to %NPM_CMD%
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

echo Handling node.js deployment.
echo %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%
ECHO %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json

echo Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
  echo Cleaning NPM cache.
  call "%NPM_CMD%" cache clean
  call "%NPM_CMD%" install
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
```

This will give the following output:

```
PS D:\home\site\wwwroot> .\deploy.cmd False "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\npm.cmd"

D:\home\site\wwwroot>echo off 
starting deploy.cmd
-------------------
False "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\npm.cmd"
all: False "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\npm.cmd"
NPM_GLOBAL: False
NPM_INFO: "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\npm.cmd"
ECHO is off.
NPM_CMD set to 
'"~1, -1"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Handling node.js deployment.
D:\home\site\wwwroot
D:\home\site\wwwroot\package.json
Install npm packages
Cleaning NPM cache.
PS D:\home\site\wwwroot> '"~1, -1"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the batch label specified - error
```

I do not understand why it doesn't know how to remove the first and last character and why it errors.  I can't see anything else wrong with the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not look after *stripping* surrounding quotes. Instead, **define variables without surrounding double quotes** as follows:

```
SET "DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=D:\home\site\wwwroot"
SET "NPM_CMD=D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\npm.cmd"
```

and then **use them surrounded in double quotes** *if necessary* as follows:

```
echo %NPM_CMD%

pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
call "%NPM_CMD%" cache clean
call "%NPM_CMD%" install
```

To apply above to your main `deploy.cmd` file, read in `call /?`

> ```
> …
> In addition, expansion of batch script argument references (%0, %1,
> etc.) have been changed as follows:
>
>     %* in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 ...)
>
>     Substitution of batch parameters (%n) has been enhanced.  You can
>     now use the following optional syntax:
>
>         %~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
>         %~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
>         %~d1        - expands %1 to a drive letter only
>         %~p1        - expands %1 to a path only
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

and apply it when necessary:

```
echo starting deploy.cmd
echo -------------------
echo %*
SET all=%*
SET "NPM_GLOBAL=%1"       1st parameter is not in double quotes already
SET "NPM_INFO=%~2"        2nd parameter is stripped of surrounding double quotes
```

Moreover, you need to *apply* delayed expansion using `!variable!` instead of `%variable%` for instance as follows:

```
(    
    SET "NPM_CMD=%NPM_INFO%"
    rem not necessary now set "NPM_CMD=!NPM_CMD:~1, -1!"
    echo !NPM_CMD!
    echo NPM_CMD set to !NPM_CMD!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove quotes around a referenced string, insert a tilde (`~`) before the parameter number.

```
%1 to %~1
```

---

Changing the start of your batch file to this;

```
echo starting deploy.cmd
echo -------------------
echo %*
SET all=%*
SET NPM_GLOBAL=%~1
SET NPM_INFO=%~2
```